# suddenly dissapearing accordion body

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-accordion

```
  const accordionStyle = {
    marginBottom: '25%',
  };
  const accordionHeadStyle = {
    marginTop: '2%',
    borderRadius: 80,
  };
  const accordionBodyStyle = {
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 80,
    borderBottomRightRadius: 80,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  };
```

```
  <Accordion.Item eventKey="0" >
     <Accordion.Header type="header" style={accordionHeadStyle} className="accordion-header-with-icon" >Accordion 1 Title
    </Accordion.Header>
       <Accordion.Body style={accordionBodyStyle}>
          ACCORDION 1 CONTENT
       </Accordion.Body>
 </Accordion.Item>
</Accordion>
```

in this structure, i tried to use accordion component in bootstrap-5. When i click on the head of the component, body section opens and after a short moment, it dissapears. What could the problem be?

Comment: which framework is this?

Comment: @AlbertEinstein possibly REACT

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=bootstrap+accordion+disappears+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.